# Selenium and Aurelia, how make test wait for the page to load and HTTP calls to complete

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, aurelia

I would like make the Test to wait until the page has loaded properly before proceeding with the next step. I used wait until but,

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time));
var elements = wait.Until(x => x.FindElements(by));
```

I am facing the problem of the element being present when the data has not been fully loaded yet.This is making the test to fail. I don't want to use the Thread.Sleep(time); since it's not a very good approach to this problem.

Is there any option like the one provided by jQuery like "jQuery.active"

I am using C# with webdriver 3 to write that test. I would like to make the test to wait for the page to complete loading and all the HTTP calls to done before proceeding with the next step is there any way to do this ?. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracking of the HTTP calls can be done using the following code

```
var javaScriptExecutor = Browser.Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            Browser.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            return javaScriptExecutor?.ExecuteAsyncScript("var cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                                                      "if (window.webpackJsonp && document.querySelector('[aurelia-app]')) { cb('Aurelia composed') }" +
                                                      "document.addEventListener('aurelia-http-client-requests-drained', function (e) {" +
                                                      "  cb('aurelia-http-client-requests-drained')" +
                                                      "}, false);");
```

above code uses the event `aurelia-http-client-requests-drained` which is triggered when all the HTTP request has been drained
For knowing if the page is composed, following code can be used

```
var javaScriptExecutor = Browser.Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            Browser.Driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            return javaScriptExecutor?.ExecuteAsyncScript("var cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
                                                      "if (window.webpackJsonp && document.querySelector('[aurelia-app]')) { cb('Aurelia composed') }" +
                                                      "document.addEventListener('aurelia-composed', function (e) {" +
                                                      "  cb('Aurelia App composed')" +
                                                      "}, false);");
```

This take advantage of the `aurelia-composed`

Answer (score 0):

Find an element in the dynamic portion of the page and wait for it. I do this all the time and it works just fine.

Comment: I tried it and it's not succeeding all the time. So if it's possible to know current state of the page it would make it lot more stable and easier to automate

Comment: Can you post a link to the page or a page like it? You might have to try different elements in the dynamic section until you find the right one.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to find any sample page, which represents my problem, Now I have found an event "aurelia-composed" which I can use to find if the page is ready. I am the using what you said and with the combination of an event have made a lot of difference.ability to know if any HTTP is running or not would be great. It would make the entire process much easier and reliable. I am still trying to find a way to achieve that